# Field format error: RB Profile cannot be created without BAID/Account Number/ORIGID in payflow pro

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing, payflowpro

when i am trying to create Recurring Billing Profile for my EMI orders.so i am getting this response:

```
[RESULT] => 7

[RPREF] => RMX50EA195C3

[RESPMSG] => Field format error: RB Profile cannot be created without BAID/Account Number/ORIGID
```

so anyone can suggest, how can i resolve  BAID/Account Number/ORIGID error?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have either the Parameter "ACCT" i.,e ACCT = < Credit Card number Which you need to apply recurring Billing > (or) BAID parameter is passed in the recurring billing rest service call to resolve this issue.